# md dialog not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm new to angular material and I'm trying to make the $md-Dialog service work. I'm using angular material's demo but somehow i can't seem to get it right. What do I need to add in order for this to work/ what am i doing wrong.

The Demo
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog

My html

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
<md-button ng-click="showAlert()" class="md-raised md-warn">Custom Dialog</md-button>
</div>
```

My JS

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$mdToast', '$animate', '$mdDialog',   '$mdMedia', function ($scope, $mdToast, $mdDialog,$animate, $mdMedia ) {

var alert;
$scope.showAlert = showAlert;
// Internal method
function showAlert() {
  alert = $mdDialog.alert({
    title: 'Attention',
    textContent: 'This is an example of how easy dialogs can be!',
    ok: 'Close'
  });
  $mdDialog
    .show( alert )
    .finally(function() {
      alert = undefined;
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quite common issue, but the order of modules in your injection array **must** match the order of modules in your function parameters.

Change this:

```
app.controller('myController', 
    ['$scope', '$mdToast', '$animate', '$mdDialog', '$mdMedia', 
    function ($scope, $mdToast, $mdDialog, $animate, $mdMedia )
```

To this:

```
app.controller('myController', 
    ['$scope', '$mdToast', '$animate', '$mdDialog', '$mdMedia', 
    function ($scope, $mdToast, $animate, $mdDialog, $mdMedia )
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you shouldn't be manually specifying the injection names. Use ng-annotate which is available in both Grunt and Gulp

https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y101